# Can I use Zend Modules to "white label" my Zend Application

Tags: php, zend-framework

I work on this Facebook application that has to be "white labeled" for different "brands".

The "white labeled" version will use the same domain and the same DB as the current one. The layout and styling of the pages will change, but the most part of the business logic will be common between the "white labeled" and the current application.

I thought that a smart way to do that would be to make a Zend Module of my current application, and to make another module for the white labeled application. This second module would "inherit" from the first one, so I won't have to duplicate the whole code. The logic specific to "white labeled" will be coded in the second module, and global features in the first one.

But from what a read about modules, the global feeling is that they must correspond to independent features, that's why I'm thinking my approach is not good...

What do you think of it and, more generally, what do you think is the good approach to white label a Zend Application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way for you to create a white label for this application is to provide a [different layout](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-layout.html) on the same module.

It would be important to keep all urls relative, including any related to theme information (css, js, images).